# How to search for files from a root directory and get the results as a dired buffer?

Tags: dired, search

I have a directory which contains directories with many music albums, and I'm doing a selection of songs according a list I found on the Internet. What I'm doing is splitting windows with the destination directory on the left, and the root directory of my music collection on the right. Sadly, I have to manually search for the song among many directories and subdirectories.

So, I was wondering if there was a way to do a recursive search by term and have the results in a dired buffer, enabling me to operate over them as I would normally do in dired.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: I found `find-name-dired` in [this doc](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Dired#Find_files_recursively).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `find-dired`, which runs a standard find command and displays the results in dired format.

This command will ask for the directory to search within, and for find-style options.

For example, to find files whose name include "salsa", use `-iname "*salsa*"` as an option.

Comment: Also `find-name-dired`